# .net: What do you prefer and why: having a function which has a DataTable parameter to fill or return a DataTable?

Tags: .net, function, parameters, datatable, return

In .net, Which method is better and why?

1. Having a function which has a DataTable parameter to fill
2. Having a function which returns a DataTable after filling it

I mean:

1.

```
Public Function Test(tb As DataTable) As boolean
    '
    '
End Function
```

2.

```
Public Function Test() As DataTable
    '
    '
End Function
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first practice can be more efficient in some cases, but the latter is generally better practice because there are no unintended side effects, and it's more like functional programming. It just depends on whether you need that efficiency or not.

Comment: I would challenge the assumption of "efficiency" here. There has yet to be a *single case* where I have chosen the former (not saying it doesn't occur, but rather -- write clean easy to maintain code *first*.)

Comment: I agree -- hence why I clearly said "the latter is generally better practice".

Answer (score 1):

Use the approach that reduces side-effects and leads to code which is easier to maintain.

I would only use the side-effect form in (extreme) cases where it is unavoidable to fulfill the functional requirements -- and then I would likely re-think the design/approach in general. My "cycles" are much more important than those of a computer.

Comment: So you use the first form . yeah?

Comment: No. The first form -- passing in the DT -- requires side-effects to fill it in. I would simply return a new DT -- the second form.

Comment: Agreed. In addition to clarity and maintainability, it also seems that the second form is easier to use in the calling code.